# Creating soap request without ns1, ns2, ns3 namespaces

Tags: java, soap, xml-namespaces, qnames

I am implementing a web service client and its request should be like this, It works with soap-ui.

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:met="http://tempuri.org/">

    <soapenv:Header>
        <met:Authentication>
            <met:Username>test</met:Username>
            <met:Password>test</met:Password>
        </met:Authentication>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <met:UpdateOrder>
            <met:ID>5311221</met:ID>
            <met:Status>true</met:Status>
        </met:UpdateOrder>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to add an Authentication header and my work so far is below ,

```
SOAPHeaderElement header=new SOAPHeaderElement("http://tempuri.org/","met");
header.setActor(null);
MessageElement usernameToken = new MessageElement(new QName("Authentication","met"));

header.addChild(usernameToken);

MessageElement userToken = new MessageElement(new QName("Username","met"));
userToken.addTextNode(userName);
usernameToken.addChild(userToken);

MessageElement passToken = new MessageElement(new QName("Password","met"));
passToken.addTextNode(password);
                
usernameToken.addChild(passToken);
_stub.setHeader(header);
```

This way I get below request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:met soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
            <ns2:met xmlns:ns2="Authentication">
                <ns3:met xmlns:ns3="Username">test</ns3:met>
                <ns4:met xmlns:ns4="Password">test</ns4:met>
            </ns2:met>
        </ns1:met>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <UpdateOrder xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <ID>4576175</ID>
            <Status>true</Status>
        </UpdateOrder>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And my question is what should I do to get the working request? I need to remove the `ns1` and `ns2` namespaces, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing some unneccesary namespace addition and adding multiple XML nodes, following simple modification to your code should be able to add header you want to add.

```
    SOAPHeaderElement header=new SOAPHeaderElement("http://tempuri.org/","Authentication");
    //**set the prefix met, though not necessary, the parser will default it to ns1 or something**/
    header.setPrefix("met");
    /**Add the username Node**/
    SOAPElement user=header.addChildElement("userName");
    /**Add the userName text**/
    user.addTextNode("MyName");
    /**Add the password node**/
    SOAPElement password=header.addChildElement("password");
    /**Add the password text**/
    password.addTextNode("myPass");
    /** Print the header if you wish to**/
    System.out.println(header);     
    /**set the header to stub, that's all, I think, you may setActor and mustunderstand**/
    _stub.setHeader(header);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you mate!  I also implemented that logic. It works.